# Range Class Selection Syntax Error Between Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, csv, range

I have been designing a macro that imports text files into Excel. The program was designed to initially import all data into sheet 1, but after getting feedback I was told to have it bring all data into sheet 2 instead. This macro had no trouble working when using commands such as `Activesheet` at the beginning of code lines, because sheet1 was always the active sheet. *Note both all sheets have their default names.

I have gone in and tried to change all my range fns to regard sheet 2 instead by typing `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")...` ,but this has given me the

> "Select method of Range class"

error. This error occurs after my initial fn to import the file using a Query table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub importtxt()

Dim txtloc As Variant

Dim build As String

Dim bit As String

Dim rng As Range

'Asks user for the build number that has been imported, then assigns that 
string to cell B1
build = InputBox("What build of SoundCheck is this?")

'Prompt Bitness
bit = InputBox("Please provide the bitness of this SoundCheck")

'Asks user for location of the Time_Memlog.txt file to be imported
txtloc = Application.GetOpenFilename _
     (FileFilter:="Text Filer (*.txt),*.txt", _
     title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=False)

'Imports .txt file designated in the txtloc string
With Sheets("Sheet2").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtloc, 
destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("$A$1"))

    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

'Clears the garbage in cell A1
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$A$1").Select
ActiveCell.Clear



'Places the string build in cell A1
Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Build:"



Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = build

Worksheets(2).Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = bit

'Selects all columns of the Time_Memlog and adjusts the column width to fit 
heading
Worksheets(2).Range("A1:S10003").Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

'Makes column headers bold text
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D2").Font.Bold = True

'Create borders around cell range A2:D2
Set rng = Worksheets(2).Range("A2:D2")

With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

'Give background color to cells A2:D2
With rng.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Aligns all cells below Column headers to the left
Worksheets(2).Range("A3:D10003").Select
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

'Give background color to cells A1:C1
Worksheets(2).Range("A1:C1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Worksheets(2).Range("D1").Select
Selection.Clear



End Sub
```

This seems like a very simple problem, yet I don't know how to get around these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers:

The bad news: You cannot `select` a cell or range from a worksheet that is not active.

The good news: No need to select a cell to assign a value (or do anything else with it). In fact you should avoid to `select` anything within VBA, there is nearly no reason to do so. Instead, simply do something like

```
with Worksheets(2)
    .range("A2").value = "Build:"
    ' or: .cells(1,1).value = "Build:"
    ...
end with
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you FunThomas. This is a good step in the right direction. So you are saying that my code below used to format a range will not be able to work in the current way I want it to? 
Worksheets(2).Range("A3:D10003").Select
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Comment: Simply change to `Worksheets(2).Range("A3:D10003").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft`

Comment: Wow, that's intuitive. I appreciate you being patient. Clearly I am new to object based programming.